# Calculating a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Z$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function:

$$
f_Z(z) =  \begin{cases}
\gamma(1 + z^2) & \mbox{ if } -2 < z < 1, \\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

a) For what $γ$ is this possible?
 b) Find the cumulative distribution function of $Z$.

Comment: For question `a` do you know what a probability distribution is and the requirements? for question `b` do you know what a cumulative distribution is and the integral/summation involved?

Comment: I know that to solve part b I need to solve the integral from negative infinity to z of fZ(z), but I don't know how to solve part a, which is why I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: which value should the integral of the PDF have over all domain?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand how to do it.

Comment: If $f_Z(z)$ is a PDF, which is the value of $P[-\infty<z<\infty]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Z(z)dz$? Or in other words, which is the probability that $z$ lies between $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: So $FZ(z)=γ(z + (z^3 / 3))$? But what would the value of γ be?

Comment: The probability that $z$ lies between $(-∞, ∞)$ = $1$?

Comment: The integral of $f$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$ equals the integral of $f$ in $[-2,1]$, because it it equal to zero outside of that interval.

Comment: @Monii Exactly. So knowing the value of the integral you can evaluate it and find $\gamma$

Comment: @gunbl4d3 thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gunbl4s2 for explaining how to get to the answer.
$a)$
$$\int_{-∞}^∞\ f_Z(z)\ dz\ = 1$$
$$\int_{-2}^1\ γ(1 + z^2)\ dz= 1$$
$$γ(z + \frac{z^3}3)\ |_{-2}^1\ = 1$$
$$γ\ = \frac16$$

$b)$
$$F_Z(z)\ =\ \int_{-2}^z\ f_Z(z)\ dz$$
$$F_Z(z) = \int_{-2}^z\ \frac16(1 + z^2)\ dz$$
$$F_Z(z) = \frac16(z + \frac{z^3}3) |_{-2}^z$$
$$F_Z(z) = \frac16[(z + 2) + (\frac{z^3 + 8}3)]$$

Comment: Notice that $F_Z(-2) = 0$ and $F_Z(1) = 1.$ That's as it must be. Do you you understand why I made sure of that? Guessing that you do. (+1)